# How can I return the finalized transcript String from a Google speech to text response?

Tags: swift, google-speech-api, google-text-to-speech

```
func processSampleData(_ data: Data) -> Void {
    audioData.append(data)

    // We recommend sending samples in 100ms chunks
    let chunkSize : Int /* bytes/chunk */ = Int(0.1 /* seconds/chunk */
      * Double(SAMPLE_RATE) /* samples/second */
      * 2 /* bytes/sample */);

    if (audioData.length > chunkSize) {
      SpeechRecognitionService.sharedInstance.streamAudioData(audioData,
                                                              completion:
        { [weak self] (response, error) in
            guard let strongSelf = self else {
                return
            }

            var finalResult = StreamingRecognitionResult()

            if let error = error {
                strongSelf.textView.text = error.localizedDescription
            } else if let response = response {
                var finished = false
                //print(response)
                for result in response.resultsArray! {
                    if let result = result as? StreamingRecognitionResult {
                        if result.isFinal {
                            finished = true
                            finalResult = result
                        }
                    }
                }
                //let textToView = response.description
                let textToView = finalResult.alternativesArray[0]
                strongSelf.textView.text = textToView as! String
                if finished {
                    strongSelf.stopAudio(strongSelf)
                }
            }
      })
      self.audioData = NSMutableData()
    }
}
```

"textToView" should only be the final string of the user's speech, however I can't seem to figure out how to actually pull this string, and ONLY this string, from the google cloud response.

To anyone who has worked with google's speech to text API, I'd really appreciate a response, as this has been troubling me for quite some time.